# Getting photo from camera and gallery

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

Hi,

I am creating a simple Android app which allows user to select photo from either photo gallery or take one using camera. After getting the selected photo, I will start another activity to do something with the photo. However I have some problem displaying the photo in another activity.

Here is the first activity to get photo:

```
public class GetPhoto extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    ImageButton ibPhotoLib;
    ImageButton ibCamera;
    final static int FROM_CAMERA = 0, FROM_PHOTOLIB = 1;
    public static Bitmap bmp;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.ibCamera:
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                    android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, FROM_CAMERA);
            break;
        case R.id.ibPhotoLib:
            Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);             
            startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, FROM_PHOTOLIB);
            break;      
        }       
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);      
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            switch (requestCode) {
            case FROM_CAMERA:
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                bmp = (Bitmap)extras.get("data");               
                break;
            case FROM_PHOTOLIB:
                Uri chosenImageUri = data.getData();            
                try {
                    bmp = Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), chosenImageUri);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            }    
            Intent intent = new Intent(GetPhoto.this, PhotoProcessing.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I start another activity (`PhotoProcessing`) and in this activity I will display the photo first. Here comes the problem if I take a photo using camera, it displays in portrait mode which is what I want. However if I choose a photo from gallery, it always displays horizontally, which is really annoying. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

And also when I try to get the width and height of the image:

```
float imageWidth = GetPhoto.bmp.getWidth();
float imageHeight = GetPhoto.bmp.getHeight();
```

- if the photo is taken from camera, `imageWidth` = `153`, `imageHeight` = `204`
- if the photo is chosen from gallery, `imageWidth` = `3264`, `imageHeight` = `2448`

for the same image.

Can anyone explain why this is so different? I am very confused.

Any solutions or suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The bitmap passed back from a camera intent is a thumbnail. Even worse, I think some manufacturers' camera implementations don't return anything.

You'll need to give the camera intent a file and then fetch the image data from the file in your onActivityResult method.

Check out the [Taking Photos Simply](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath) guide for implementation details.